# Saving a DataFrame object on Google Colab and loading the pickle file on my local computer results in a recursion error

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, google-colaboratory

I was using google colab to train some XGB models and was saving the results in a pickle file after which I would load and read them on my local computer for analysis. This was working fine for the past few months till recently where I could no longer load the pickle file.

I recreated the error as such:

On google colab:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,2,3]]
with open('./test.pkl', "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(pd.DataFrame(a), file)
with open('./test.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)
print(b)
```

b is printed as intended.

On a local computer (tried on 3 different computers, all had the same recursion error.):

```
with open('./test.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)
print(b)
```

Running this will give

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

And using pycharm debugger to check what the object b is in the debugger mode results in

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Unexpected error, recovered safely.
```

The strange thing is that it works perfectly as long as I read the pickle file on google colab again but fails when I read it on a local computer...

Lastly, this problem only occurs if I pickle a DataFrame. I tried pickling a dictionary and a list of numbers and there was no issue.